# Editing the *bookmark list* buffer on Emacs

Tags: emacs

On Emacs (using [Bookmarks+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus)), if I type `C-x r l` I can open the buffer `*Bookmark List*` and navigate through my bookmarks.

On this buffer, if I type <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a given bookmark, Emacs opens the bookmark, and if I type `r` Emacs allows me to edit it (rename). However, this mode of editing requires me to type my edits from scratch on the minibuffer (i.e. I need to provide the new name of the bookmark and the full new path of the bookmark).

I was wondering if there is a way to edit the `*Bookmark List*` buffer directly, as if I was editing any regular buffer, so that I don't have to re-type the new name or path of the bookmark (in case I want to keep parts of them) from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

No, the `*Bookmark List *` buffer is not directly editable. But there are commands (keys) for editing bookmarks that are displayed there.  You mentioned <kbd>r</kbd>.  There are also <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>, depending what part of a bookmark you want to change.  Not to mention several keys for editing a bookmark's tags.

As for recuperating existing text to reuse (edit) it, that should be trivial. The current value is available as a default value (<kbd>M-n</kbd>, <kbd>M-p</kbd>). Or you can copy it from a help buffer: <kbd>C-h RET</kbd> gives help on the current-line's bookmark (in buffer `*Help*`), and with a prefix arg the full bookmark record is shown, i.e., the Lisp sexp representing the bookmark, which is in your bookmark file (`~/.emacs.bmk`, by default).

The current values of any part of a bookmark that you would want to edit are thus easily available - you should never have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

You could always edit your `.emacs.bmk` file directly.

Comment: Yes! But then make sure not to run `(bookmark-save)` before you relaunch Emacs or all the edits will be overwritten by the old bookmarks.

Comment: Actually, that comment of mine above was valid for bookmark+. Vanilla bookmark does not have that issue and changes made directly to the bookmark file do not get rewritten when `(bookmark-save)` is run.